# How to manage down servers in a reverse proxy list with nginx?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am trying out nginx load balancing functionality.

Now the config looks like this:

```
...
upstream myapp1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    server 127.0.0.1:4001;
    server 127.0.0.1:4002;
    server 127.0.0.1:4003;
   }
...

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://myapp1;
    }
```

Now, when I want to upgrade any of the instances, I have to stop it, update the code, and restart.

So, when the server is going down, how do I make nginx not use it in its balancing routine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are upgrading a server, edit the nginx configuration and add `down` keyword in the `server` line in the `upstream` block for the particular server.

Then issue command `service nginx reload`, or similar command for your distribution which makes nginx re-read its configuration. Now nginx won't use that upstream server, so you can upgrade and restart the service without any effect on users.

After that, you can remove the `down` keyword, and reload nginx configuration.

Comment: Can nginx proxy server can automatically detect whether the server is down and handle this ?

Comment: According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html, it will mark node down if it cannot be connected with configurable number of retries.